# Setting unknown property: yii\web\UrlRule::GET

Tags: api, rest, yii2, composer-php, yii-url-manager

I have this error and I don't know to solved.

I created an api endpoint with Yii2. A few days ago the endpoint was working but now it doesn't and raise this error:

```
{
name: "Unknown Property",
message: "Setting unknown property: yii\web\UrlRule::GET index",
code: 0,
type: "yii\base\UnknownPropertyException",
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php",
line: 161,
stack-trace: [
"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(521): yii\base\Object->__set('GET index', 'index')",
"#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\web\UrlRule), Array)",
"#2 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)",
"#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(374): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)",
"#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(153): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\web\\UrlRule', Array, Array)",
"#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\web\\UrlRule', Array, Array)",
"#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\UrlManager.php(212): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)",
"#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\UrlManager.php(154): yii\web\UrlManager->buildRules(Array)",
"#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(107): yii\web\UrlManager->init()",
"#9 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)",
"#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(374): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)",
"#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(153): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\web\\UrlMana...', Array, Array)",
"#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\web\\UrlMana...', Array, Array)",
"#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(133): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)",
"#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(563): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('urlManager')",
"#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php(180): yii\base\Application->getUrlManager()",
"#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(75): yii\web\Request->resolve()",
"#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))",
"#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\forkandjoin\api\index.php(13): yii\base\Application->run()",
"#19 {
```

There is my urlManager configuration:

```
modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/api/modules/v1', // base path for our module class
            'class' => 'app\api\modules\v1\Api', // Path to module class
        ]
    ]
'components'  => [
        'urlManager'  => [
            'enablePrettyUrl'  => true,
            'showScriptName'  => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'class'  => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller'  => 'v1/demo',
                'patterns' => [
                    'GET index' => 'index'
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

I created this simple example with a Demo controller and a simple index endpoint in order to show to get a more clear picture about the problem.

How can I solve this problem? why is return unknown property.

### Info

```
OS: Windows 10.
Composer: version 1.0.0 2016-04-05 13:27:25
Yii version: 2
```

### my composer file

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "linslin/yii2-curl": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more information just lemme know but I need to solve this problem now or I'll be a crazy man without return.

### Update: Controller

It is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\Controller;

class DemoController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            [
                'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
                'formats' => [
                    'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex(){
        return "index ";
    }
}
```

### Yii2 routing guide

I did these configuration following the official guide about [Routing](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html):

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'user',
    'extraPatterns' => [
        'GET search' => 'search',
    ],
]
```

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wow, thank you guys. I had been working the whole weekend trying to solve this problem and based on your feedback and researching I found a little error in the configuration. In Yii2 guide explain the configuration in two piece of code. So I had to change my code from this:

```
'rules' => [
    'class'  => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller'  => 'v1/demo',
    'extraPatterns' => [
        'GET index' => 'index'
   ]
]
```

to this one:

```
'rules' => [
    [ // array item
      'class'  => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
      'controller'  => 'v1/demo',
      'extraPatterns' => [
          'GET index' => 'index'
       ] 
    ]//close the array item
]
```

Well, the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

`Setting unknown property: yii\web\UrlRule::GET index` says you are using incorrect UrlRule class. It should be yii\rest\UrlRule.
Check your component's config to make sure that you are using the correct one.

Comment: @Hutsi I did it. In `rules => []` is set `'class'  => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',`

Comment: @robsch yep, waiting for the comments from author

Comment: I updated the question. I set the modules configuration and the controller. If you need more information lemme know. Thank you for your faster feedback.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html#$patterns-detail) it should be:

```
        'rules' => [
            'class'  => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller'  => 'v1/demo',
            'patterns' => [
                'GET' => 'index' // removed ' index' in key
            ]
        ],
```

If this solves your problem I'm wondering why it worked until a few days. Maybe this route wasn't called yet?